# How to fill a spinner with data from a webservice?

Tags: android

I have a web service that returns the following result

```
[{"id":"01", "Nombre":"star","llegada":"17/05/2019 12:00:00 a.m."},
{"id":"02", "Nombre":"marcela","llegada":"20/05/2019 12:00:00 a.m."},
{"id":"03", "Nombre":"san jorge","llegada":"21/05/2019 12:00:00 a.m."}]
```

How to insert it into an Androidstudio spinner?

Comment: Checkout here  :  https://abhiandroid.com/ui/spinner

Comment: Please be more specific.  What have you tried?  What is not working?

Comment: I am new to the theme of android not yet and tried something this is the web service http://201.147.199.119:90/WSp2/crudService.asmx?op=lista

Comment: Simple  first extract json code and store in arraylist...

Comment: sorry you'll have some example of how to do it